# Select Query Using 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I have 3 tables

**person**
person_id 
username_email

**language_skill**
person_id 
language_id 
language_teaching 
language_learning

**language**
language_id 
language_name

I want to select the username_email of users that teach English for example. 
I don't know how to structure my select statement using joins.

```
SELECT person.person_id, person.username_email FROM language_skill 
INNER JOIN person ON language_skill.person_id = person.person_id
INNER JOIN language_skill.language_id = language.language_id
WHERE language_skill.language_teaching = 1 AND language.language_name = English
```

The error I receive is

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.language_id WHERE language_skill.language_teaching = 1 AND language.language_na' at line 3

Comment: what is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your query you missed second `on`  and English should be put into `'` brackets

Try:

```
SELECT person.person_id, person.username_email FROM language_skill 
INNER JOIN person ON language_skill.person_id = person.person_id
INNER JOIN language on language_skill.language_id = language.language_id
WHERE language_skill.language_teaching = 1 AND language.language_name = 'English'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use alias for each table:

```
SELECT b.person_id, b.username_email FROM language_skill a
INNER JOIN person b ON a.person_id = b.person_id
INNER JOIN language c ON a.language_id = c.language_id
WHERE a.language_teaching = 1 AND c.language_name = 'English';
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change person.username_email into b.username_email. I just fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The second join is incomplete.
Syntax is

```
[type] JOIN [table] ON [condition]
```

Corrected

```
SELECT
    person.person_id, 
    person.username_email 
FROM language_skill 
    INNER JOIN person ON language_skill.person_id = person.person_id
    INNER JOIN language ON  language_skill.language_id = language.language_id
WHERE language_skill.language_teaching = 1 AND language.language_name = 'English'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Simple join

```
SELECT P.`person_id`, p.`username_email` FROM PERSON P , language_skill LS ,
language L WHERE P.`person_id` = LS.`person_id` AND L.language_name  = 
'ENGLISH' AND L.language_id =LS.`language_id`
```

Comment: I would suggest against using ANSI-89 syntax as it is easy to miss `JOIN` predicates, leaving you with an expensive cartesian product. I have also seen people "solve" this issue by doing a `SELECT DISTINCT` to "fix" it.